# DB2 How to use case with multiple conditions?

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 Server and I want to select data depending on the condition.
If I have the Value `Value` in the ColumnX, ColumnY or ColumnZ it should search for it between the `TB2.Column1` and `TB3.Column1`
My statement is a bunch of left outer joins but it looks like that:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (TB1.ColumnX || TB1.ColumnY || TB1.ColumnZ) = 'Value'
    THEN Statement1
    ELSE ' '
END AS MyColumn
FROM
TB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TB2 ON TB1.JOINCOL = TB2.JOINCOL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TB3 ON TB2.JOINCOL2 = TB3.JOINCOL
WHERE TB1.Column1 between TB2.Column1 and TB3.Column1
```

But it doesn't work, is there a mistake in the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check for multiple equalities using just a single expression.  You may use the following syntax trick:

```
CASE WHEN 'Value' IN (TB1.ColumnX, TB1.ColumnY, TB1.ColumnZ)
     THEN Statement1 ELSE ' ' END AS MyColumn
```

The alternative to this would be to repeat the full equality check for each column:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN TB1.ColumnX = 'Value' OR
         TB1.ColumnY = 'Value' OR
         TB1.ColumnZ = 'Value'
    THEN Statement1
    ELSE ' '
    END AS MyColumn
FROM
TB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TB2
    ON TB1.JOINCOL = TB2.JOINCOL
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB3
    ON TB2.JOINCOL2 = TB3.JOINCOL
WHERE
    TB1.Column1 BETWEEN TB2.Column1 AND TB3.Column1;
```

If you need to refer to the `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause, then you have two choices.  First, you may subquery your current query, and assign an alias to the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN ... AS exp
    FROM TB1 ...
) t
WHERE exp = ...
```

Or, you may avoid the subquery and just repeat the entire `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah yes, I used the OR statement so far, but your first one seems much more elegant. How can I filter it with the Where statement but only if I have a match in the condition? Use another case in the where statement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you either have to repeat the `CASE` expression, or else subquery your current query and filter on an alias associated with the `CASE` expression.

Comment: How do I handle the where expression then? 
Where CASE WHEN (condition) THEN Statement ELSE [Nothing?] END CASE. Thanks in advance!